# Where can I find open source Android apps?

Tags: applications, open-source

I'm not an open source zealot, but I generally prefer to use open source applications over proprietary ones if they stack up. Are there any directory sites with reviews, ect that specialize on open source Android apps? The closest thing I've been able to find is [Wikipedia's list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_open_source_Android_applications).

Comment: Looks like the Wiki list you found is a good answer to your own question. FYI: You can answer your own questions here and even accept your own answers.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can install F-droid to get a market-style repository of Free and Open Source android apps:

http://f-droid.org/

Comment: You are free to submit apps.There are over 200 apps in the queue, however.To help, convert submission into metadata form and submit via git.Full instructions @ f-droid.org!

Comment: [Review of F-Droid by Android Central](http://www.androidcentral.com/f-droid-foss-application-store-your-android-phone)

Answer (score 14):

Google Code seems to be the predominant place for open source Android apps:

http://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=label:Android

Comment: Note: the above answer was written a LOOOONG time ago when Android was fairly new and lots of people hosted open source Android projects on Google code.  There may be other places people tend to host them now.

Answer (score 1):

Can't find any directories that specialize in open source apps, but you could do worse than a simple search on one of the regular app directories (like [this](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=open+source) or [this](http://www.androlib.com/r.aspx?r=open+source))

Otherwise, I'd say your Wikipedia list looks like a pretty good source.

Answer (score 1):

This is another source:

http://www.aopensource.com/

Answer (score 0):

How about crawling [Aptoide](http://www.aptoide.com/)? Not all are Open Source, but there are [many](http://www.aptoide.com/search/view?search_top=open%20source)!

Comment: As anyone and his little sister can have his own repository on Aptoide, it might be worth pointing out which ones can be considered safe. See e.g. [How safe is it to use Aptoide?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/74618/16575) and [Android Markets: How safe are alternative sources?](http://android.izzysoft.de/articles/named/android_markets_safe_to_use) I recommend sticking to the "Apps" repo, which is manually curated by the Aptoide team itself – and to those you know having a trustworthy maintainer as well.

Answer (score 0):

As far as my own experience goes, Aptoide is really great. I discovered it when I was trying to find something similar to vshare for the iphone on android**`*.I downloaded the APK Installer for the app directly from their website - aptoide.com.*`** I don't really know anything about f-droid, I might try i though. I did try blackmart before and didn't go very far with it, it didn't feel trustworthy. That was awhile ago though.Anyway, I have issues with google play and try to avoid it as much as possible, so I am solely dedicated to aptoide and it hasn't failed me yet. As far as safety goes, I occasionally install software such as AVG and Advanced Mobile Care if I feel I might be taking a risk. I haven't been afflicted with any malware from aptoide's markets yet! On the other hand, my 10 yr. old son is not as critical as I am when he chooses to download something from them on his own tablet, he also refuses to run any software like AMC & AVG and his tablet does have adware.But for as far as it goes , it doesn't seem to be doing any real damage to his device.
\

Comment: This is a commentary. Please stick to main topic. It's not worth telling a reader that you didn't try F-droid or that you don't trust Blackmart (unless you've a source to confirm it's shady). Google Play (no need to mention). Besides, you're relying too much on AVG and some other apps as a security measure which itself is a flaw. That said, could you mention the link to source code of AVG and other app? I've doubts reserved for them. About the last part, nowadays malwares are either spywares or adwares -- they don't usually damage your device, they just spy on you. They breach your privacy.

Answer (score -1):

You can install F-droid or you can go to [fossdroid.com](https://fossdroid.com) (frontend web of F-Droid) to browser open source apps by trending, popularity, ect... (with screenshots).