# How safe is the Aptoide apk?

Tags: security, permissions, aptoide

I was going to install Aptoide, but some of the permissions raised concerns for me.

Why does it need my precise location, need to be able to add or remove accounts, create accounts and set passwords, and find and use accounts on my device?

Comment: Related (no duplicate): [How safe is it to use Aptoide?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/74618/16575)

Comment: I used Apptoide it was great. Even tho I however did get a little virus. I use family plan and I had to give away all my devices(some)and buy new one. I DO NOT suggest you using this. Mine craft stopped working after 3 day or something

Answer (score 4):

Aptoide is also an app store like Play Store which needs an account. This is like your Google account for Play Store. So it will have permissions (just like Play Store) for creating/modifying accounts (only for Aptoide). Location access is for viewing apps according to your location. Aptoide is safe but be careful with the apps downloaded from it.

Comment: Minor correction: You don't need an account to use the Aptoide app (I've never created an account there, but still use it). You'll only need it if you want to rate/comment/report or use your own repo. But for those cases, the app must be able to deal with accounts, absolutely right :)

Answer (score 0):

Aptoide is safe however users upload apps to Aptoide's stores, any apps that you download from Aptoide should have a green shield with a check mark (meaning they have no viruses). If they do not, it means that they haven't been scanned for viruses.

Comment: Does it also have any protection from spywares, adwares and ransomwares? These are more common and dangerous than a virus for Android.

Answer (score 0):

I am using aptoide basically for searching an app that is not available in my country. But i heard that some paid apps are found freely on aptoide which is surely not a good option.

Comment: Please mention why it is not a good option, from the perspective of piracy, hacking the app, malware, or something else?

Comment: I have found many malwares which are hidden in disguise like cracker, patcher etc. Sometimes the green button is also misleading.

Comment: Will it be possible to name any such app that you encountered as malware? Anyhow, whatever the info you've mentioned and is yet to mention, please do so in the answer itself and not in the comments. Click [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/110230/edit) to edit your answer.

Comment: Also, do you have any answers to the specific question, about why it needs those permissions? I don't believe the questioner was specifically concerned about whether that market has bad apps, so much as why the app itself needed the permissions it's asked for.