# Update APK Installed App

Tags: google-play-store, apk

I recently installed an app to my phone using an APK, because this app is not available in my country. When I looked it up in my **Google Play Store** (*I only get to view this app in my **wishlist**, because it doesn't show up when I just search for it*), there is a mark on my wishlist that this app is now installed on my phone, but when I view the app, there is still the notice message of "*This item isn't available in your country.*"

Will I be able to receive the update? If not, is there a way to update this app?

Comment: Not if you update from the Play Store. You could try an alternative store like **Aptoide**, though, which will show you the available updates when the apk's signature matches the signature of the one you installed.

Comment: You can update the app using a VPN and fake GPS.

Comment: @SuperThomasLab - I tried using VPN and fake GPS, but it causes a malware on my phone, which drains the battery when it is on idle. Had to restore my phone to factory settings to get rid of it. So I'm not "in" with this solution. Maybe I just did something wrong, but I just installed "Hotspot Shield Free VPN", but it doesn't work. Maybe this solution will work for most people.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman I searched for **Aptoide**, looks good to me. I'll try it when a new update for the app has been released. Cheers!

Comment: I used "TunnelBear" and "fake GPS".

Answer (score 2):

**No**. The only way to update the app is download the new version apk and install it.

I had similar experience with a game they released only for certain parts of the world. Then they released an update that I had to install in order to play the game, but since it wasn't available in my country I had to look for the updated apk and install it outside Google Play Store.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll have to test it out first when a new update has been released.

Comment: Ivo, your answer is *mostly* correct but not *fully* – the app might be available at [tag:alternative-markets] as well (see e.g. the first comment on the question itself).

Comment: @Izzy Thanks! I'll try the Aptoide market as suggested by DeathMaskSalesman in my post. I'll test it out when a new update has been released.

Comment: Take care which repos you chose there then, Logan – for details, see [How safe is it to use Aptoide?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/74618/16575)

Comment: @Izzy Well yeah, but if the developer uploads to alternative markets, he'd make it unavailable to me there too. So its exactly the same thing as downloading it from anywhere on the internet. SOmeone went backed up the apk from their phone, then uploaded it somewhere else on the internet. I typically distinguish two places where you can get your apps, google play store and everything else.

Comment: You're wrong with that, Ivo. Several developers keep their apps updated in multiple places (usually GPlay and Amazon, sometimes GPlay and F-Droid). While you're mostly correct when it comes to Aptoide, where some repos do exactly that, it's often done regularly though – so updates might be a bit delayed, but still are available and the user gets notified.