# Why are apps on Aptoide newer than the Play Store?

Tags: applications, updates, aptoide

I have seen many of the usual apps such as YouTube, Facebook, and Google Maps even, that have a newer version in Aptoide rather than Google Play Store.

How is this possible since Google Maps and YouTube **originally come from** Google Play Store? Are these apps safe to download from the 'apps' store in Aptoide?

Also on the YouTube app in Aptoide, it doesn't have the 'Trusted' shield, it says 'Unknown'.

Comment: People may be uploading the various betas for these apps.

Comment: As you didn't tell which repo you've found them in, it might well be fakes with some "lovely addons" you'd better not try. Please see my answer to [How safe is it to use Aptoide?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/74618/16575) on how to make sure you don't get "crap" (e.g. stick to "safe repos" like the one called "Apps", and watch out that the apps you download have a "green shield").

Comment: @Izzy  Yeah i did, i mentioned asking are they safe to download from 'apps' store in Aptoide?  because thats where youtube, maps, etc are available as newer versions. if its beta, it usually SAYS BETA. but in the current case, it doesnt. it just says newer versions are available. newer than google playstore?? i just dont understand.. this happens often.

Comment: Ah – sorry. I always said the name is a bit confusing. Especially when people spell it lowercase and not with an "uppercase A" :) Guess [Andy's answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/152702/16575) matches those candidates then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Staged rollouts](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6346149?hl=en), alpha and beta testing.

APKMirror states testing builds clearly, for example on [Google Apps](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-search/google-search-6-2-28-release/):

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Basically this. Since the update rollout from Play Store is staged, some people get the update earlier than the other, and they share the APK to other (e.g. XDA, APKMirror, Aptoide) for other people to sideload it. It almost always happened to me when reading new features of Google apps' update, when I haven't got the update yet.

Comment: Ok kinda makes sense now.